# Autolayout Y constraint between UITableView and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am having trouble with autolayout constraints. I want to have a view which is organised as such:
[image: view organisation]

All contained views have leading and trailing constraints to the content view, no problem there. The Wrapper view has a constant height, a top constraint to the ContentView. The collection view has a top constraint to the Wrapper's bottom, the TableView has a top constraint to the Collection's bottom and a bottom constraint to the Content view.
The problem is, If I do not set a fixed height to the CollectionView I have autolayout problems. But I don't want either of the TableView or the CollectionView to have a fixed height. Any ideas?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the ContentView can have a 
dynamic height, I would like it to fit to its content.

All constraints are:
[image: All constraint description]

Thanks

Comment: cells height for the collection and tableView static ??

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do, is to divide the remaining space, after setting a height constraint for wrapper view, between collection view and table view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By not setting height constraints to neither the TableView nor the CollectionView, you're not giving the Auto-Layout engine enough information to generate your layout.

Probably the best way to do this would be using a proportional height constraint for either the collection or table view, this way you can set the height to a "non-fixed" value.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious as auto layout engine is unable to determine y position of your table view. Even though you have specified that:

collectionview.bottom = tableview.top

it could be virtually anywhere inside the vertical space.

You should have rough idea about how much space each of your content view children occupy. Give them relative height constraint.

Something like:

```
wrapper view.height = 0.3 * content view height
collection view.height = 0.35 * content view height
table view.height = 0.35 * content view height
```

The way to do it is to give equal height constraints to each in XCode, then modify multipliers to 0.3, 0.35 and 0.35 by going inside each constraint.

**Needless to say:** The rule is to make sure all multipliers add up to 1.

This is the best approach which is device-agnostic, and you don't have to do it for each size class.

I have detailed tutorial about the underlying principles of Auto layout, [over here](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-app-design-blog-fix-xcode-autolayout-errors-warnings/).

Comment: Well, the problem is that the collectionView and the TableView both have dynamic height, cells can be added at runtime. I might have forgotten to say that the ContentView can have a dynamic height aswell, and I would like it to fit to its content.

Comment: Collectionview and tableview are inherently scrollviews - you could have unlimited rows but still have fixed height for them. Conversely, if you want dynamic height for all your child views, consider putting your contentview under a scrollview. For guidelines on how to do autolayout for scrollview, follow this nice article: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/auto-layout/uiscrollview-storyboard/